# FullCalendar - mark time between hours

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

Hello I use FullCalendar and I have a problem with the mark time between hours. Example:

```
[{ "start": "2017-07-27 10:00", "end": "2017-07-27 11:30" }, { "start": "2017-07-27 11:30", "end": "2017-07-27 12:00" }]
```

[image]

How to fix this? or tell me what I have to change in the configuration / css?

```
{
    header: {
        left: '',
        center: '',
        right: 'prev,next'
    },
    lang: 'pl',
    locale: 'pl',
    dayNames: ['Niedziela', 'Poniedziałek', 'Wtorek', 'Środa', 'Czwartek', 'Piątek', 'Sobota'],
    dayNamesShort: ['Nd', 'Pn', 'Wt', 'Śr', 'Cz', 'Pt', 'Sb'],
    height: options.height,
    defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
    columnFormat: 'D.MM ddd',
    minTime: options.minTime,
    maxTime: options.maxTime,
    displayEventTime: false,
    smallTimeFormat: 'H:mm',
    timezone: 'Warsaw/Poland',
    buttonIcons: false,
    buttonText: {
        next: options.buttonText.next,
        prev: options.buttonText.prev
    },
    allDaySlot: false,
    slotMinutes: 30,
    //slotDuration: '00:30:00',
    //slotDuration: '00:15:00',
    events: getEvents(options.events, options.optionsItem),
    eventRender: function(event, element) {},
    viewRender: function(view, element) {

        if (view.name === 'agendaWeek') {

            element.find('.fc-day-header').each(function() {
                console.log($(this).text());
            });

        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show us on jsfiddle ? :) Btw, it can be a FC bug.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jso51pm6/40/ looks good... hmm but how to remove empty row under an hour?

Comment: What empty row? I dont see any empty row

Comment: You speak about the first column? is because of the `slotMinutes` variable.
You can set  `slotDuration: '00:60:00',` slotMinutes is deprecated..
and after that you can define the slot size, after that you should set the row height by css.

Comment: it works Thx :)

Comment: You are welcome! I posted as an answer as well. ;)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `slotMinutes` variable.

You can set `slotDuration: '00:60:00'`, *slotMinutes is deprecated..* and after that you can define the slot size, after that you should set the row height by css.